# Negetive Y axis on TSVB not working in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to get -ve Y-axis on TSVB Kibana but it does not work. Tried following this tutorial but still does not work I can't find an aggregation called "Calculations" in my kibana.

```
https://www.elastic.co/blog/master-time-with-kibanas-new-time-series-visual-builder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Kibana version does not have an aggregation called Calculations. It has aggregation called Bucket script which could do similar things. Try to use the same painless script in Bucket script aggregation and it would work.

Use the below for -ve Y-axis(where the rate is a variable in bucket script)

```
params.rate >0 ? params.rate * -1 : null
```